# How is this multiple indirection working?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int i=10, j=20, k=30;
    int *ip1, *ip2, **ipp;
    ip1=&i;
    ip2=&j;
    ipp=&ip1;
    *ipp=ip2;
    *ipp=&k;
    cout<<*ip1<<endl;
    cout<<*ip2<<endl;
    cout<<**ipp;
    getch();
}
```

The line `cout<<*ip1;` prints 30 to console, can anyone explain how? The output is -

```
30
20
30
```

I was expecting -

```
10
20
30
```

I don't know how multiple indirection is working in this case.

Comment: if the last two outputs are clear, why dont you remove them? It would make the question much easier to read

Comment: I thought it would be easier to understand the problem this way.

Comment: @AseemBhardwaj Yes it might be difficult to determine which part is necessary, which part is not, if you don't understand these statements completely. Anyway I think you could determine it now. :)

Comment: Yup. Thanks to you sir! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `ipp` points to the variable `ip1` due to this statement

```
ipp=&ip1;
```

So any dereferencing of the pointer `ipp` yields the value of the pointer `ip1`. Thus for example this statement

```
*ipp=ip2;
```

is equivalent to

```
ip1 = ip2;
```

and this statement

```
*ipp=&k;
```

is equivalent to

```
ip1 = &k;
```

As result `ip1` contains the address of the variable `k` while `ipp` contains the address of `ip1` itself.

And these statements

```
cout<<*ip1<<endl;
//...
cout<<**ipp;
```

produce the same result except the newline character supplied by the call  of the operator << with `endl` in the first statement. They output the value of the variable `k`.

Answer (score 2):

> The line cout<<*ip1; prints 30 to console, can anyone explain how?

Because you changed the value of `ip1` via `ipp` (pointer of pointer), from pointing to `i`, to pointing to `j`, then to pointing to `k` at last.

```
ipp=&ip1;         // make ipp point to ip1
*ipp=ip2;         // dereference on ipp, change the value of pointee (i.e. ip1) to ip2
                  // i.e. make ip1 point to j
*ipp=&k;          // change the value of pointee (i.e. ip1) to the address of k
                  // i.e. make ip1 point to k
cout<<*ip1<<endl; // now we get 30 (i.e. the value of k)
```

Comment: Thanks. One thing, if we omit *ipp=ip2;  Output is still the same, is that line unnecessary?

Comment: @AseemBhardwaj Yes it might be, because the effect of `*ipp=ip2;` is overwritten by `*ipp=&k;` immediately.

Comment: Thanks, again. I was thinking about the same.